# Bootstrap columns are overlapping each other on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid

I'm trying to have 2 columns within Bootstrap. The first one (the navbar) will be full width (col-12) the other column (the content) will be 1/3 and 2/3 of the page so col-4 and col-8. However, on mobile devices, the second row is overlapping the first row as seen in this picture (I added a red and black border on the rows to see the problem):

[image]

Now when I do a margin-bottom on the first row I see the following:

[image]

So far some reason the navbar is overlapping the row

The code of the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And the code of the body:

```
<div class="container shadow">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
         {....}
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 card border-0">
            <div class="leftColumn">
               {...}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 card border-0">
            <div class="rightColumn">
                {...}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

From the bootstrap documentation:

'Fixed navbars use position: fixed, meaning they’re pulled from the normal flow of the DOM and may require custom CSS (e.g., padding-top on the ) to prevent overlap with other elements.'

Link to codepen:

https://codepen.io/witteWas/pen/xxGMYYa

**EDIT:**

Issue was solved by putting nesting the 2nd row inside the first row.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card has-shade">
        <div class="col-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
          {...}
         </nav>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 card border-0">
              {...}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12 card border-0">
              {...}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please share link to online code editor.

Comment: https://codepen.io/witteWas/pen/xxGMYYa

Answer (score 0):

## Firstly, your column classes are confused.

The class `.col-md-` means...

> (medium devices - screen width equal to or greater than 768px)

the class `.col-lg-` means...

> (large devices - screen width equal to or greater than 992px)

If you have col-md on one of your it already as a matter of fact, includes all the devices 992px or greater. There is probably some conflicts arising from the use of both these classes together.

This seems to be repeated in the body section as well. Use one of these two classes and if you need custom css applied to certain resolutions rather use a media query in your styles.css file.

Comment: I want a different column layout based on the device that is being used. So 4 / 8 on large devices and 6 / 6 on medium devices. Seeing the bootstrap documentation this should be possible:

`<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
<div>`